# cannot resolve symbol mainactivity after importing from github

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github, android-gradle-plugin

I made a project, imported it to github, moved it to a group url (https://github.com/friendsies/Alerta) and then went to import it so that I'd be updating it instead of the nonexistent one on my personal URL.  I imported it, but it won't build, because a bunch of symbols in AndroidManifest.xml can't be resolved.  I think I need to add my src directory as a source, but i'm not sure how to do that, and more importantly I'd like to know what I could change so that future people importing my project won't face the same problem.  Thanks in advance.  The symbols that aren't resolving btw are

```
android:name=".MyParseApplicationClass"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
<activity android:name=".SignupActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with your Build.gradle that whether all dependency and compile are their and also check the compile version for eg"compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'". Check compile SDK version and Target SDK version after resolving build the project.

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyParseApplicationClass"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity">
    </activity>
    </application>
```

Correct the above too in your manifest. Hope it works

Comment: the compile/target sdk version is 23, the same as the other project which worked.  I changed things in my manifest but it still cannot resolve those symbols

Comment: Did You migrated the project properly. Its an eclipse project. [Migrate to android studio](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)